# syntax for complex jquery selector inside live listener

Tags: jquery

I first used the following syntax in my code but it did nothing with no error:

```
$("div[data-content-tab]").find("input").on("change input paste keyup",function(){
    console.log ($(this).val());
})
```

I have switched to this second syntax and I got the following error:

```
$(document).on("change input paste keyup",'div[data-content-tab].find("input")',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   div[data-content-tab].find("input")

What is the correct syntax for **both** syntax above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `div[data-content-tab].find("input")` to `div[data-content-tab] input`,due to `.find("input")` is invalid syntax

```
$(document).on("change input paste keyup",'div[data-content-tab] input',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Thanks. What about first syntax?

Comment: The first syntax is also okay,but it will not work for dynamic added element

Answer (score 1):

The first example looks completely working. Probably there is some issue with your html.

```js
$("div[data-content-tab]").find("input").on("change input paste keyup",function(){
    console.log ($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-content-tab='1'><input /></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. on other answer I recognized that this not works on dynamically added elements.